# .slideUp() after mouse been out for 2 seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a slide thing and I only want the #content div to slide up after the mouse has been out of .content for more than 2 seconds.  but i want to be able to put my mouse back over, if it is within those 2 seconds. Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/YZDGu/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`:

```
var slideTimer;

$(".container").hover(function(){
    $('#content').slideDown();
    clearTimeout(slideTimer);
},function(){
    slideTimer = setInterval(function() {
      $('#content').slideUp();
    }, 2000);
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GFpHH/**

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YZDGu/3/) with use of set/clearInterval.

See [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

Comment: that isn't exactly what i want, because if i put my mouse out for one second, and then put it back over it will slide up and that is not what i want to happen.

Comment: @AndrewMilson Updated to include check for whether the mouse has been rehovered.

Answer (score 1):

Add a delay:

```
$(".container").hover(function(){
        $(".container #content").slideDown();
},function(){
        $(".container #content").delay(2000).slideUp();
});
```